# What would be the best way to input a date and a time range on that date?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

Im developping a MEAN stack web application where one of the functionalities is that a user can reserve a room to organize an event.

An event can only last one day. I want the user to select a certain date and time when the event takes place. I used datetime picker for the starting moment of the event, and an input field for the duration (in minutes). This isn't so user friendly in my opinion.

Anyone got an idea on how to implement it better ? I've been thinking about a datepicker with 2 timepicker (for start and end time) or just 2 datetime pickers. I don't prefer the second option because a user can only select 1 date, not a date range. For example a user can select monday 12th of march 2018 as a date, but he/she cannot select a multiple dates (from monday to friday for example).

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

- There can be multiple events on the same day in the same room. The times just can't overlap. For example there can be an event from 4 to 5 p.m. and another event from 6 to 8 p.m. (There are 4 rooms in total. A user can select a room of choice (if its free at the given time)).
- An event can only last 1 day. A user can only select 1 date not multiple.

Comment: A few questions: you mention that an event can only last one day — can there be multiple events on the same day in the room? If events only last one day, what should a user selecting multiple dates (from Monday to Friday) do? Show the available single days to reserve in that range, and then when a user selects a single day, drill-down to available hourly segments?

Comment: I edited the post with some more info. Good suggestion. I will take a look at it. Thanks

Comment: In that case, I'd prefer something like a slider with two handles for start and stop, stepped to the minimum scheduling interval (say :15 or :10 minutes). Pick a date, then show rooms with availability on that date. Then have some indication as the user drags start and end sliders as to whether the interval is free for a given room (can make start slider handle red, e.g., if it overlaps end of an existing event). You could make the slider correspond to horizontal timelines for each room's current schedule, or just list the occupied times per room and provide validation feedback.